# DefaultTablemodel delete rows if the row has a specific value JAVA

Tags: java, defaulttablemodel

I would like to delete rows if the first row String "Windows" but, it doesn't work well, it removes rows if the String value is "Windows"
My code. Any help is going to be appreciated. :)

```
                                    for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
                                        if ((String) model.getValueAt(i, 0) != "Windows") {
                                            model.removeRow(i);
                                        }
                                    }
```

Comment: after model.remove(i); write ' break;'; this will work if you want to delete the first row containing "Windows". if this isn't what you want explain more :)

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: what is the result you're getting, and what do you expect be precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare strings you can with [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) directly

Keep in mind that deleting a row reduces the size of your model, you could control subtracting the iterated for when you delete a row or not, not do all comparisons

```
for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) { 
   if (!model.getValueAt(i, 0).equals("Windows")){

   model.removeRow(i);
   i-=1;  // 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
if (!model.getValueAt(i, 0).equals("") && model.getValueAt(i, 0).equalsIgnoreCase("Windows"))
{
 model.removeRow(i);
}
```

For String comparision always we tend to use equals method.If you want you can have a null check like model.getValueAt(i, 0)!=null.

Answer (score 0):

It works, but i have a lot of row it delete only one row, and i have to click a tree if i would like to delete all of value if value is not equal "Windows" [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPSLw.jpg)